# Overlay special properties

Tags: overlays

How can I configure overlay text to be read-only? I know there is a text property `read-only`, but that's not exactly what I want to use.

Answer (score 1):

There is no predefined overlay property `read-only`.

You can probably get the behavior you want by using property `keymap` or `local-keymap`.

You can use a keymap value that binds all normally self-inserting keys to do nothing or raise an error.

If you do that only for what you know at overlay-creation time to be self-inserting keys then that might not be sufficient. You can instead bind *all* keys in that keymap to a command that does nothing (e.g. `ignore`) or that raises an error.

Someone else might have a better answer.  But that's what I'd try first: use property `keymap` or `local-keymap`.

---

I also wonder what your actual use case is.  Maybe this is an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/231821)?

Comment: Thanks. Sounds like good idea. I will do that. My use case is that I want to hide some portion of buffer using overlay display property and I dont want that hidden part of buffer to be editable. It would be best to have completely immutable part of buffer, but killing <backspace> will be enough for me.

Comment: Abort abort. I tried it and it failed. I assigned nil to <backspace> but characters were still vanishing. Maybe I will be forced to create mu custom backspace handler...

Comment: `nil` removes the binding in that particular keymap (whatever keymap you bind it to `nil` in). If bound in another map that is active, it may still do something you don't want. Try binding it to `ignore` instead of `nil`.

Comment: thanks, I will try that